# How to using IF Function in column with text and number instead

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a help for my case below.

[image]

How can I get data from that column with this specific case :

1. If Days > 0 : result is greather than SLA
2. If Hours = 1 and Minutes > 0 : result is greather than SLA
3. If Hours > 1 : result is greather than SLA
4. Except point 1 to 3 : result is less than equal to SLA

It's so difficult for me to using IF functio with that specific case above.
I have tried using this formula :
=IF(M2="Days" > 0,"> SLA", IF(M2="Hours" = 1 & M2="Minutes" > 0, "> SLA", IF(M2="Hours" > 1, "> SLA", "<= SLA")))
But the result is not the way I want to.

Please help me guys.

Comment: Can you paste the values as text so we do not need to retype them?  Also what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: And basically you are saying if the time is greater than 1:00 it is `> SLA` not sure why we should even worry about 1 and 2 as they will always be greater than 1:00.

Comment: This should work for your sample data but not for 1 hours 0 minutes. `if(mid(m2,8,1)<>"0",">SLA","<SLA")`

Comment: @findwindow I've tried your formula and it works to filter time SLA. Big thanks bro.